# pdfmake jquery plugin browser popup block

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, browser

I am using a jquery plugin whose name goes like [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/). I am able to create the whole pdf of my requirements but the problem comes in when I request the browser to open the pdf file. Rather than opening the pdf, browser says popup blocked. After clicking and selecting to allow popups from this site it opens the pdf. My script :

```
 <script>
    var docDefinition = {




   content: [
     { text: 'BirdVision Invoice', style: 'header' },
     { text: 'Bill To', style: 'anotherStyle' },
     { text: '<?php echo $row->client_name; ?>', margin: [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ] },
     { text: '[Company Name]', margin: [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ] },
     { text: '[Street]', margin: [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ] },
      { text: '[POST/ORT]', margin: [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ] },
      { text: '[Phone/Email]', margin: [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ] },
     { text: 'Bill For', style: [ 'header', 'anotherStyle' ] },
      { text: 'Total :', alignment: 'right',  margin: [ 5, 50, 100, 10], fontSize: 22, bold: true},

     { text: 'If you have any questions feel free to contact us!! ', alignment: 'center',  margin: [ 0, 500, 0, 0]},

   ],

   styles: {
     header: {
       fontSize: 22,
       bold: true
     },
     anotherStyle: {
         margin: [ 5, 50, 10, 10 ],
      fontSize: 15,
       bold: true,
       italic: true,
       alignment: 'left',

     }
   }
 };

     pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, sorry for any ambiguity in the question. The browser blocked pdf to open because of the automatic request generated by my system. So, I created a button to involve human interaction like :

```
<button class = "btn btn-default" onclick="pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open()"> Open PDF </button>
```

No popup blocked message from any browser now.